# Mongodb aggregate frequencies of every field (dichotomous) in one query

Tags: mongodb

i am fairly new to mongodb and try to develop a nice way of evaluating a so called multiple choice question.

The data looks like this:

```
db.test.insertMany([
  {
    Q2_1: 1,
    Q2_2: -77,
    Q2_3: 1
  },
  {
    Q2_1: -77,
    Q2_2: -77,
    Q2_3: 1
  },
  {
    Q2_1: 1,
    Q2_2: 0,
    Q2_3: 0
  },
  {
    Q2_1: 0,
    Q2_2: 1,
    Q2_3: 0
  }
])
```

In this example we have 4 probands, who gave answers to 3 items.
Every field can contain one of three values -77, 0, 1

-77: proband did not see the item. So it is neither calculated in the 'base' NOR in 'abs'.

0: proband did see the item, but did not choose it. (counts for 'base' BUT NOT for 'abs')

1: proband did see the item, and chose it. (counts for 'base' AND for 'abs')

now i want a result for every item. So item 1 (Q2_1 has the key value of 1 and so on)

so item 1 would have been seen by 3 probands so the 'base' would be 3.
it would have been chosen by two probands so the 'abs' would be 2.
and therefore the 'perc' would be 0.666666.

expected result array:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "abs": 2,
    "base": 3,
    "perc": 0.6666666666
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "abs": 1,
    "base": 2,
    "perc": 0.5
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "abs": 2,
    "base": 4,
    "perc": 0.5
  }
]
```

Is it possible to do this evaluation in one aggregation query and get this expected result array?

thanks for help :-)

Comment: the documents are 4 but the expected results are 3, is this what you need? also if you can explain a bit more how those key/abs/base/perc are produced, for example the abs=2 in the last one how its produced?

Comment: @Takis Hi, i thought that i explained it pretty well. Yes i want one result per item. abs is the absolute count of probands who chose that item. so for key_3 (item Q2_3) you have 2x1 so abs=2. base is the count of all probands who have been able to chose that item: you have 4x 0 or 1 so base=4. and the percentage of chosen items is then 4/2 = 0,5 (50%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- `$objectToArray` to remove the data from the keys (you should not save data on fields, fields are for the schema only, MongoDB query language is not made for data in fields)
- unwind and replace root
- group and 2 condition based accumulators `base` and `abs`
- add the `perc` and fix the key, split on `_` and take the second part
- sort by key

*query is bigger because data on fields doesn't work good in MongoDB, so try to avoid it

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6331a66978a49d87828514cf) (you can put the mouse in the end of each stage to see what it does)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unset": ["_id"]}, {"$set": {"data": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$unwind": "$data"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$data"}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$k",
    "base": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$v", -77]}, 0, 1]}},
    "abs": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$v", 1]}, 1, 0]}}}},
 {"$set": {"key": {"$arrayElemAt": [{"$split": ["$_id", "_"]}, 1]}}},
 {"$set": {"_id": "$$REMOVE", "perc": {"$divide": ["$abs", "$base"]}}},
 {"$sort": {"key": 1}}])
```

Comment: thank you!! really good. where did you learn all this?
Btw. what do you exactly mean with data in fields? We do market research and hat huge problems with sql database, because of thousands of cross filter possibilities. the vertical key, value approach needed too much query time.

Comment: question number is data, and if you want to group by question number like above, you need this information to be as value not as field. Think maybe this also for each document  `{"questions" : [{"number" : 1, "value" :1},{"number" : 2, "value" -77},{"number" : 3, "value" 1}]}` here the question number is on the right as value so we can group by it etc, to learn more about aggregation see documentation, the Reference, that has all operators